# Object reached heap limit - debugging a Javascript SIGILL error on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, debug, wordpress

When i run my js script for my plugin in Wordpress. The page freezes, times out and returns a SIGILL error. I can't see any errors in web dev tools, the page just freezes.

I installed minidump_stackwalk using cargo.

```
sudo apt install cargo
cargo install minidump-stackwalk
```

Then I ran Chrome in debug mode,

```
google-chrome --enable-logging --v=1
```

and I ran the Crash Report through minidump_stackwalk to interpret the dump files. It gives me the chrome library stack trace which is not useful.

```
minidump_stackwalk ~/.config/google-chrome/'Crash Reports'/07*.dmp
```

The chrome debug log that I get when i run this bash command (on linux) is a little more useful.

```
tail -n 100 ~/.config/google-chrome/chrome_debug.log
```

This is the output from my chrome debug log.

```
[140960:1:0721/122133.762869:ERROR:v8_initializer.cc(688)] V8 javascript OOM: (Reached heap limit).
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997566:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x34740a187720
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997588:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x34740a186ca0
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997593:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x3474091aff00
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997597:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x347409b3e760
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997601:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x34740a186f40
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997605:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x347409b3e4c0
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997609:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x34740a186e60
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997613:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x3474078d6a00
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997617:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x34740a1865a0
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997621:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x34740a185f80
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997840:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x347409b3ee60
[133755:134289:0721/122133.997850:VERBOSE1:bus.cc(708)] Requested to remove an unknown filter function: 1 with associated data: 0x347409b3ebc0
[133755:133755:0721/122133.999826:INFO:render_frame_host_impl.cc(11505)] RenderFrameHostImpl::MaybeGenerateCrashReport url = https://staging.rebelcitytour.com/test-maps/, status = 3, exit_code = 132
```

It looks like a JS object is seg-faulting or running out of memory. Possibly it's an infinite for loop.

Problem is though, i've no idea which JS object to look at. Like I stated, chrome web dev tools is crashing along with the web page. All i get is a SIGILL error and the crash report.

I've tried debugging the code block by block, but the behaviour seems kinda erratic. Sometime it'll work with code commented out, sometimes it won't. I've cleared the cache everytime.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's *not* an infinite loop, [try increasing JavaScript heap size](https://www.positioniseverything.net/javascript-heap-out-of-memory) to allow deeper debugging. See also this [V8 article on heap size](https://v8.dev/blog/heap-size-limit), and [this, in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643406/raise-chrome-js-heap-limit).

Comment: it's almost certainly an infinite loop. thanks anyway. I couldn't find an answer to this question.